# How do I get input from the console in Red language

Tags: rebol, red

I'm writing a console program (target MSDOS) in Red language and I need to ask the user to enter a character or a string, then to press `Enter`.

I can't seem to find how to do it, I've read the docs here (http://www.red-by-example.org/index.html) to no avail.

I tried something like this:

`read.red`

```
Red [

]

print "Please make your choice then press Enter"
x: input
print x
```

It works in the "Red Console" with `red read.red` but when I compile with `red -r -t MSDOS read.red` I get an error:

`Compiling C:\apps\red-read\read.red ...
*** Compilation Error: undefined word input
*** in file: C:\apps\red-read\read.red
*** near: [
    input
]`

How do I ask for input from a Red console program?

I'm using Red version: `--== Red 0.6.3 ==--`.

Comment: I believe you should be using Windows as your compile target instead of MSDOS for Windows.

Comment: @AlexanderRyanBaggett thank you for your suggestion, I'm trying to make a console app, but just to see if it works, I tried with target Windows and Darwin and I get the same  error about input

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, I did some testing and got it working on my end. You need 2 things.

1) You need the latest build, not 0.63. You can grab the automated build from master from [the downloads page](https://www.red-lang.org/p/download.html).

2) You need a reference in your file to use the console. Here is the updated code which will work on Windows with the latest version.

```
Red [

]
#include %environment/console/CLI/input.red

print "Please make your choice then press Enter"
x: input
print x
```

This info was buried away in an [article](https://github.com/red/red/wiki/%5BNOTES%5D-Compiling-with-console-functions) on github.  Also, you were right about MSDOS.

Comment: Your solution works, I was able to compile. Thank you.

Comment: Link updated: https://github.com/red/red/wiki/%5BNOTES%5D-Compiling-with-console-functions---input,-ask